# Copy-paste typo in Stack Exchange, Inc. Privacy Policy

Tags: bug, terms-of-service

In the last section of [Stack Exchange, Inc. Privacy Policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), a left side is not reflecting text on the right, and in reality is bluntly copy-pasted from the previous section:

[image]

It seems that what had to be on the left side in the plain-english section is in the 1st paragraph on the right side.